# Calling an Object from one class to another in C#

Tags: c#, class, object, call

I understand that this question has been asked an I've read the other instances, however, I could not make much sense out of the answers. I am trying to create a body fat percentage calculator and I need to call the BMI from one class to the other and I have no clue how.

```
namespace ParkerProgramming3
{
    public class BMICalc
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BMICalc calObj = new BMICalc();
            string strName = calObj.GetName();
            double dWeight = calObj.GetWeight();
            double dHeight = calObj.GetHeight();
            double BMI = calObj.GetCalc(dWeight, dHeight);


            //Console.Read();

        }
        public string GetName()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the BFP Calculator!");
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
            string strName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + strName);
            Console.WriteLine("First, we need to calculate your BMI");
            return strName;
        }
        public double GetWeight()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your weight (in pounds)?");
            string sWeight = Console.ReadLine();
            double dWeight = Convert.ToDouble(sWeight);
            return dWeight;
        }
        public double GetHeight()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your height (in inches)?");
            string sHeight = Console.ReadLine();
            double dHeight = Convert.ToDouble(sHeight);
            return dHeight;
        }
        public double GetCalc(double GetWeight, double GetHeight)
        {
            double BMI = 703 * GetWeight / (GetHeight * GetHeight);
            return BMI;
        }

    }

}
public class BFPCalc
{
    public void BMICalc()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is your `BFPCalc` class in another namespace? Which class should call which? There's too little info here.

Comment: "call the BMI from one class to the other" is not clear, and you don't even show any attempt at what this means.

Comment: Don't use names like that in your `GetCalc(...)` method. They will work but it's absolutely never a good idea to name a variable the same way as a function before. For more info check out some programming style tutorials.